# How to gey Sessionkey from new FaceBook SDK in iphone

Tags: iphone, facebook, session, sdk, key

Can any one help me in this:

I used new FaceBook SDK, and there is no Session seen any where. How can we get Session key after logging in to Facebook.

Im using '- (void)fbDidLogin;' method after login to facebook.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using the Facebook connect api. You'd have to create a FBSession object and initialize in either initWithNibName or ViewDidLoad. This object automatically gets populated with the session key once the user has been authenticated.

```
    FBSession *session = [[FBSession sessionForApplication:@"bla bla" secret:@"bla bla" 
                    delegate:self]retain];
```

Comment: IN new Facebook Sdk, there is no FBSession. There is many changes from old to new.